# Fragments doesn't destroy on finish() and stay on reopening application

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-finish

On exit from the application I got this :

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
finish();
```

in onBackPressed() method

But if after I close my application I try to start it again - I got error and logs say that fragment that was last and supposed to be destroyed toghether with application is trying to get Activity's context and that context , of course, no longer exists.

How do I destroy my app completely and why doesn't finish() destroy it?

Comment: Did you try getActivity().finish(). Somehow you need to get the Context from your fragment.

Comment: but I finish() from my Activity directly, not from a Fragment